# asp:Content CSS Style from Master

Tags: css, asp.net

It seems the style links don't carry over in to the pages where you identify your asp:content tags.  What is a way to make the styles already styling the master page, also style the content pages?  I have four style sheets at the moment.  A master sheet, and three other sheets that apply based on window size.  I've switched to using a master page and now my content position is not behaving at all.

Comment: Everything I'm reading seems to suggest that my styles should be applied.  #confused...  I am styling from within the <head></head> tags on the master sheet.  It is working correctly to everything on the master sheet.  Everything that comes from the asp:content doesn't get the style.  What do I need to check for that's not so obvious?

Comment: Are you applying styles based on element IDs for server controls? Those will change when you use a master page. Try viewing the rendered source of your page, or using your browser's developer tools to inspect the elements.